# How to simulate multiple DHCP client using dhtest?

Tags: shell, dhcp

I would like to simulate multiple DHCP client using dhtest.However,the below script is not working as expected.Can someone help to fix the problem or provide any script which can simulate dhcp clients and also bind to respond for ARP requests.

```
#!/bin/sh
#simulate 255 IPhones requesting DHCP


# Apple OUI = D8:96:95
BASE="d8:96:95:08:96"
FROM=$1
shift
TO=$2

if [ -e $FROM ]; then FROM=1; fi
if [ -e $TO ]; then TO=1; fi

for i in `seq $FROM $TO`
do
    LSB=`echo "obase=16; $i" | bc`
    MAC="$BASE:$LSB"
    HNAME="`uname -n`-fakehost-$i"
    #CMD="$HOME/bin/dhtest -m $MAC -V -i eth1 -h '$HNAME'"
    CMD="$HOME/bin/dhtest -m $MAC -i eth1 -h '$HNAME'"
    echo $CMD
    $CMD
    sleep 1
done
```

Comment: *the below script is not working as expected* is not a great problem description.  You should go into more detail..

Comment: But I'm guessing your problem is the single quotes around `'$HNAME'` when you define `CMD`.  Try getting rid of those and see if your script works.